# SoundManager 2 and iPhone

Tags: iphone, html, audio, soundmanager2

The following code works in my desktop browser but not in Safari on my iPhone, it does display the alert() but doensn't play the audio. What am I doing wrong?

```
soundManager.url = '/assets/backend/swf/';
soundManager.preferFlash = false;
soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
soundManager.onready(function(){
    function playSong(){
        soundManager.createSound({
            id: 'song_<?=$song->ID?>',
            url: '/backend/song/play/<?=$song->ID?>',
            type: 'audio/mp3'
        }).play();
    }

    $('#play').click(function(){
        alert('playSong()');
        playSong();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, iPhone doesn't like "auto-played" sounds, and they require the sound to be played from user interaction.

In your case, the iOS browser must not like the fact that you're creating the sound AND THEN playing it back immediately.

Give this variant a try and see if it works for you:

```
soundManager.url = '/assets/backend/swf/';
soundManager.preferFlash = false;
soundManager.useHTML5Audio = true;
soundManager.onready(function(){
    // Create the sounds here (don't call play)
    soundManager.createSound({
        id: 'song_<?=$song->ID?>', // It is not cool to put PHP here, read below!
        url: '/backend/song/play/<?=$song->ID?>',
        type: 'audio/mp3'
    });

    $('#play').click(function(){
        var soundId = 'song_<?= $song->ID ?>';
        soundManager.play(soundId);
    });
});
```

As a side note: I'd advise you AGAINST mixing JS and PHP in that way. Check this SoundManager2 example on how to "augment" a regular MP3 link like this:

```
<a href="blabla.mp3">Click here to play blabla</a>
```

into something that plays an MP3 onclick:
[SoundManager2 documentation](http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/demo/page-player/)

Regards and good luck!